# C# Displaying new received Frame on a WPF GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, zeromq

Im currently working on a client, which receives frames from a server as byte-array. These byte-arrays will converted to a BitmapSource.
However it seems nothing happens when i try to display the arriving frames on my WPF GUI.

This is the method which receives the bytearray, converts it and displays it on the GUI.

```
public void runSocketRoutine(){

while (true){

    byte[] content = new byte[8294400];
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Messages.");

    using (ZMessage message = subscriber.ReceiveMessage()){
        Console.WriteLine("Message received!");
        string pubID = message[0].ReadString();

            /*receive bytearray from publisher*/
            content = message[1].Read();
            Console.WriteLine("size of content: " + message[1].Length);

            /*create BitmapSource out of the bytearray you receive.*/
            BitmapSource source = BitmapSource.Create(1920, 1080, 72, 72, PixelFormats.Bgra32, BitmapPalettes.Gray256, content, 1920 * 4);
            if (source != null){
                Console.WriteLine("source is created");
            }
            /*display image on screen*/
            videoView.Source = source;
            Console.WriteLine("videoView updated");          

    }
}
}
```

And this is my xaml content.

```
<Window x:Class="FrameByteArrayTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FrameByteArrayTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Image x:Name="imgView" Stretch="UniformToFill">
        </Image>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

I even tied to display a choosen png on the GUI by creating a BitmapImage passing by an URI-Object with the given data-path. It seems as if I cant display any picture anymore if i dont do it in the main-method.

I'll be grateful for every hint.
Many Greets

Comment: Shouldn't you use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in that case ?

Comment: You are executing an infinite loop without giving the UI thread a chance to actually display the bitmap. Does the `subscriber` object probably have an event where you can attach a handler method to asynchonously receive new bitmap frames? If not, you should perhaps actively receive a frame in the Tick handler of a DispatcherTimer.

Comment: aye youre right. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something tells me you aren't doing I/O on your UI thread.  Try this:

```
using (ZMessage message = subscriber.ReceiveMessage()){
    Console.WriteLine("Message received!");
    string pubID = message[0].ReadString();

    /*receive bytearray from publisher*/
    content = message[1].Read();
    Console.WriteLine("size of content: " + message[1].Length);

    /*create BitmapSource out of the bytearray you receive.*/
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
      BitmapSource source = BitmapSource.Create(1920, 1080, 72, 72, 
        PixelFormats.Bgra32, BitmapPalettes.Gray256, content, 1920 * 4);
      if (source != null){
         Console.WriteLine("source is created");
      }
      /*display image on screen*/
      videoView.Source = source;
      Console.WriteLine("videoView updated");          
    }));
}
```